# Registration form in php doesn't work

Tags: php, forms, registration

I'm trying to make a registration form in PHP.
I check if the fields are empty.
If a field is empty i make a $var and if the $var is setted i show the error and don't make the query..
but when i test the source it run the query and don't show the error if the fields are empty..

please help me i can't find the problem..

```
  <?php
    require_once('./lib/recaptchalib.php');

    $username = ($_POST["username"]);
    $real_name = ($_POST["real_name"]);
    $password = ($_POST["password"]);
    $password1 = ($_POST["password1"]);
    $email = ($_POST["email"]);
    $socialid = ($_POST["socialid"]);

    function generateRandomString($length = 25) {
        $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        $randomString = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
        }
        return $randomString;
    }
    $random_activate = generateRandomString();
    require_once('./lib/config_mail.php');

    $scid_check = strlen($socialid);

    if($scid_check != 7) {
        $print_error = "Il PIN deve essere composto da 7 caratteri, al momento ne ha $scid_check";
        $check_errors = 1;
    }

    if($password != $password1) {
        $print_error = "Le password non corrispondono!";
        $check_errors = 1;
    }

    if($username != "") {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM $db_account.account WHERE login = '$username'";
        if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
            $count = $result->num_rows;
            if($count == 1) {
                $print_error = "Username gi&agrave presente";
                $check_errors = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    if($email != "") {
        $query1 = "SELECT * FROM $db_account.account WHERE email = '$email'";
        if ($result1 = $mysqli->query($query1)) {
            $count1 = $result1->num_rows;
            if($count1 == 1) {
                $print_error = "Indirizzo E-mail gi&agrave presente";
                $check_errors = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    if(!$resp->is_valid){
        $resp_check = 2;
    } else {
        $resp_check = 1;
        $print_error = "Il codice di verifica &egrave errato!";
        $check_errors = 1;
    }


    if ($username == "" || $real_name == "" || $password == "" || $password1 == "" || $email == "" || $social_id == ""){
        $check_errors = 1;
    }

    if($check_errors == 1){
        $print_empty = "Uno o piÃ¹ campi risultano vuoti!";
    } else {
        $status_account = "INACTIVE";
        mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO $db_account.account (`login`,`real_name`,`password`,`email`,`social_id`,`create_time`,`gold_expire`,`silver_expire`,`safebox_expire`,`autoloot_expire`,`fish_mind_expire`,`marriage_fast_expire`,`money_drop_rate_expire`,`securitycode`,`status`) 
        VALUES ('$username','$real_name',PASSWORD('$password'),'$email','$socialid','$create_time','$gold_expire','$silver_expire','$safebox_expire','$autoloot_expire','$fish_mind_expire','$marriage_fast_expire','$money_drop_rate_expire','$random_activate','$status_account')") or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
        $print_notice = "Account registrato, ti abbiamo inviato una e-mail di verifica a $email !";
        $to      = $email;
        $subject = $site_name;
        $headers = 'From: '  . $email_admin . "\r\n" .
            'Reply-To: '  . $email_admin . "\r\n" .
            'Content-type: text/html' . "\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);        
    }


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning strings to $print_error or/and $print_empty isn't enough. You have to output the content of the variable(s) by yourself with "echo".

But anyway, **your mysql-queries are vulnerable and unsafe**! Please learn all stuff around "SQL-Injection".

Read this first please and make your script a little more secure:
http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php